# Flip transition of the form is not smooth in iOS

Tags: codenameone

```
@Override
protected void postSplash(Form f) {
  f.animateHierarchyAndWait(2000);
  f.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
  f.setTransitionOutAnimator(new FlipTransition());
 }
```

The flip animation of the form works in simulator but when I tested in iOS device, it looks like it stops for a second when it flips.

```
@Override
protected void beforeSplash(Form f) {
    f.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x414143);
    f.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);

    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
    splashImg = theme.getImage("splash_bg.png");
    splashContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Label.CENTER));
    f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, splashContainer);

    splashLabel = new Label();
    splashLabel.setIcon(splashImg.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 2 + 50));
    splashLabel.setVisible(false);
    splashContainer.add(splashLabel);
    splashContainer.getAllStyles().setMarginTop(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()/3);
}

@Override
protected void postSplash(Form f) {
    splashLabel.setY(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight());
    splashLabel.setVisible(true);

    f.animateHierarchyAndWait(1000);
    f.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
    f.setTransitionOutAnimator(new FlipTransition());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutable images are slower in iOS. The transition paints the UI onto a texture image for flipping so this takes a fraction of a second that might be noticeable.

Normally it shouldn't be noticeable but drawing to mutable images is much slower than drawing to the screen on iOS. So this depends heavily on the content of the form in terms of UI elements and their design.

Comment: the screen has a logo that slides upward before it flips. I have updated all my codes above. Thankyou.

Comment: Is this on an old device?

Comment: I checked it in a ipad and ipod too with version 9.3.5

Comment: Which iPad version? Are we taking iPad 3 or lower? iPods are generally a bit under powered.

Comment: Yes, this has some cost on older devices, I don't think there is much we can do to improve that on the older devices.